# Socket server on Nest.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, sockets, nestjs

I want to run a socket server on Nest.js(Not WebSocket server).

I need something like this

```
server.listen(port, host, () => {
        console.log('TCP Server is running on port ' + port + '.');
    });
    let sockets = [];
    server.on('connection', function (sock) {
        console.log('CONNECTED: ' + sock.remoteAddress + ':' + sock.remotePort);
        sockets.push(sock);
        sock.emit('test', "test");
        sock.on('data', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            gpsInformationDecode(data);//for example
            return true;
        });

        sock.on('close', function (data) {
            let index = sockets.findIndex(function (o) {
                return o.remoteAddress === sock.remoteAddress && o.remotePort === sock.remotePort;
            });
            if (index !== -1) sockets.splice(index, 1);
            console.log('CLOSED: ' + sock.remoteAddress + ' ' + sock.remotePort);
        });
    });
```

But on Nest.js.

How can I do it?
I don't need to use WebSockets, because I want to use this microservice with a GPS tracker, which can't send data by WebSockets.

P.s.: All nest js docs and manuals have information only about WebSockets.

Comment: Have you tried Socket.IO? It not necesarily using Wbsockets under the hood, but you must have Socket.IO integration on both sides, client and server.

Comment: I can't because I have a GPS tracker with TCP/UPD socket connection. I can`t change it.

Comment: Would be great if you could share the way to communicate with this GPS tracker since is a key factor to provide you a compatible solution. You say that supports TCP connections and I can't see why would be a problem to use `http`, `ws` or `wss`.

Comment: Socket != WebSocket

Answer (score 0):

Inside bootstrap function in main file u can use
`let net = require('net');`

```
const bootstrap = async () => {

        var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
            socket.write('Echo server\r\n');
            socket.pipe(socket);
        });
}
```

or like separate module

```
import { Injectable, Module } from "@nestjs/common"
let net = require('net');



@Injectable()
export class SocketService {
  constructor(
  ) {}


upSocket(port: number, host: string) {
    var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
      socket.write('Echo server\r\n');
      socket.pipe(socket);
    });
    
    server.listen(port || 1337, host || '127.0.0.1');
 }
}

@Module({
  providers: [SocketService],
  exports: [SocketService]
})
export class SocketModule {}
```